# Error using Rcpp from R

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm trying to call a C++ code from R. I've installed the packages Rtools and Rcpp. And I set up the 2 environment variables for g++.

But when I run this code:

```
library(inline) 
library(Rcpp)
src <- ' 
  std::vector<std::string> s; 
  s.push_back("hello");
  s.push_back("world");
  return Rcpp::wrap(s);
'
hellofun <- cxxfunction(body = src, includes = '', plugin = 'Rcpp', verbose = FALSE)
cat(hellofun(), '\n')
```

I get:

```
Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! 
> cat(hellofun(), '\n') 
Error in cat(hellofun(), "\n") : could not find function "hellofun"
```

Though, g++ is detected:

```
> system('g++ -v')
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\Rtools\GCC-46~1.3\bin\G__~1.EXE
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/rtools/gcc-46~1.3/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-w64-mingw32
Configured with: /data/gannet/ripley/Sources/mingw-test3/src/gcc/configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=i686-w64-mingw32 --with-sysroot=/data/gannet/ripley/Sources/mingw-test3/mingw32mingw32/mingw32 --prefix=/data/gannet/ripley/Sources/mingw-test3/mingw32mingw32/mingw32 --with-gmp=/data/gannet/ripley/Sources/mingw-test3/mingw32mingw32/prereq_install --with-mpfr=/data/gannet/ripley/Sources/mingw-test3/mingw32mingw32/prereq_install --with-mpc=/data/gannet/ripley/Sources/mingw-test3/mingw32mingw32/prereq_install --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-targets=all --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --enable-libgomp --enable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-fully-dynamic-string --disable-nls --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --disable-win32-registry --disable-rpath --disable-werror CFLAGS='-O2 -mtune=core2 -fomit-frame-pointer' LDFLAGS=
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.6.3 20111208 (prerelease) (GCC)
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Might be useful to set verbose to TRUE to get more information about what went wrong. Also, using `cxxfunction` from inline is kind of old fashion. Nowadays, we use `cppFunction` or `sourceCpp` which is nicer.

Comment: A copy/paste of your code works for me on `W7_64` `R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)`, `Rcpp ‘0.10.4’`  (yes, yes I know I'm behind!). A little more info about your setup will be required. (`sessionInfo()` etc).

Comment: I found this example here (https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/RStan-Getting-Started). My aim is to use Rstan but it is based on Rcpp. Could you please tell me how to set the verbose mode?

Comment: I'm using inline_0.3.13 and Rcpp_0.10.6.

Comment: @MarkMorrisson: `verbose=TRUE` in the `cxxfunction()` you call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `cppFunction`, this works for example:

```
library(inline) 
library(Rcpp)
src <- ' 
SEXP hellofun(){
 std::vector<std::string> s; 
  s.push_back("hello");
s.push_back("world");
return Rcpp::wrap(s);
}'
hello_fun <- cppFunction(src)

hello_fun()
[1] "hello" "world"
```

Comment: When I try your code, I get the following error:
MAKE Version 5.2  Copyright (c) 1987, 2000 Borland 
Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, showOutput = showOutput,  : 
  Error occurred building shared library.

Comment: So you have Borland make in your PATH ahead of the Rtools aheads of the Rtools. That. Does. Not. Work.

Comment: Well, after putting the rtools path ahead of all other paths, it worked! Though, after running rstan (which failed), the line cppFunction(src) does not compile anymore... The error is too long to be reported in the comment.